# Cannot Set SeriesCollection.Values Property in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts

I am trying to set SeriesCollection.Values property however, I get the error "Unable to set the Values property of the Series class". I have tried Google for possible solutions, but none have worked yet.

I have used xlNewApp.Sheets("Synchronized Data").Range("H2:H117") in place of "'Synchronized Data'!$H$2:$H$117" and this has not worked either.

I have had some success with typing an array in (e.g. "={58, 77, 65,106}") of the actual data I want to graph, however I would like to avoid looping through all my data to create the necessary array.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

The code looks like this:

```
    xlSheetCount = xlNewWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Dim chart As Excel.Chart = xlNewApp.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add(After:=xlNewWorkbook.Worksheets(xlSheetCount))
    xlNewWorkbook.ActiveChart.Name = "Chart_Efficiencies"

    xlNewWorkbook.Sheets(xlSheetCount).name = "Chart_Efficiencies"
    xlNewApp.Charts("Chart_Efficiencies").Select()
    xlNewApp.ActiveChart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter

    xlNewWorkbook.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
    With xlNewWorkbook.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter
        .Name = "HgT Removal Efficiency"
        .XValues = "'Synchronized Data'!$A$2:$A$117"
        .Values = "'Synchronized Data'!$H$2:$H$117" <----------- Problem Here
    End With
```

UPDATE:
The Code does not error if that line is:

```
xlNewApp.Sheets("Synchronized Data").Range("H2:H15").Value
```

When H15 becomes H16, I get the error again

Answer (score 1):

i know this is old and not the subject but i've been looking for that a very long time... and google gives this link, so i'll just put that there in the hope it will help someone..

```
    .(X)Values = New Object() {value1, value2, etc..}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace these lines:

```
    .XValues = "'Synchronized Data'!$A$2:$A$117"
    .Values = "'Synchronized Data'!$H$2:$H$117" <----------- Problem Here
```

With this:

```
.XValues = Sheets('Synchronized Data').Range("$A$2:$A$117")
.Values = Sheets('Synchronized Data').Range("$H$2:$H$117")
```

?